# Google Sheets App Script - Get values from formula instead of writing to cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-macros

My script sets the values of a whole sheet by using an arrayformula.

```
sheet.getRange("A2").setFormula("=ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(FILTER(Furniture!$A$2:$S$15000,ISNA(MATCH(Furniture!$A$2:$A$15000,Shopify!$F$2:$F$50000,0)))))");
```

Is it possible to get these values as an array, without updating the sheet? At the moment, the best I can think of is getting the values from the sheet after applying the above formula. There must be a more efficient way.

Comment: The efficient way would be to recreate what the formula does(language 1) in apps script (Language2). Efficient, but not easy , unless you know both languages. SO doesn't offer free code translations.

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the values from 'Furniture' sheet that aren't included in the values from 'Shopify' sheet, and then, delete the duplicate values from the result. You can get the values for each sheet range using `getRange()` [1] function combined with `getLastRow()` [2] function in order to get the range up to the last row with data (You can change this and simply use your entire A1 notation for each sheet). You can use JS `filter` function [3] to filter the values from Furniture that aren't in Shopify, and finally `reduce` function [4] to get rid of the duplicate values. Below is the working code, you need to replace the Spreadsheet ID and run `getUniqueValues` function from the editor, this will log you the resultant array.

```
function getUniqueValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('[SPREADSHEET-ID]');
  var furnitureSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Furniture');
  var shopifySheet = ss.getSheetByName('Shopify');

  //Get the range for each sheet based on last row with data
  var furnitureArray = furnitureSheet.getRange('A2:A' + furnitureSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().join().split(",");
  var shopifyArray = shopifySheet.getRange('F2:F' + shopifySheet.getLastRow()).getValues().join().split(",");

  var resultArray = furnitureArray.filter(function(furnitureValue) {        
    if(shopifyArray.indexOf(furnitureValue) == -1) {
      return true;
    }
    return false
  });

  resultArray = resultArray.reduce(function(a,b){
    if (a.indexOf(b) < 0 ) a.push(b);
    return a;
  },[]);

  Logger.log(resultArray);
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow

[3] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

[4] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce